# How to gather coverage data on XCode 9.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-coverage, xcode9.3

I updated Xcode to 9.3 and now cannot find where is the 'Gather coverage data' checkmark.
Where is it located now?

**This is how it used to be**

[image]

**This is how it is presented now**

[image]

Comment: Edit Scheme => Test Debug => makes sure you are selecting "Options" - Code Coverage: Gather coverage for...

Comment: @AhmadF worked ✅

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You can find it in options of `Test` tab named as `Gather coverage for`:**

You just need to keep selected `all target` here.

[image]

Comment: the upper bar which contains those 4 entries (Info, Arguments, Options and Diagnostics) is missing under Test section in my scheme, do you have a clue how to show this bar ?